# Constructing passive voice with " wollen "

Tags: passive, modals

The formula for making passive voice with all modals are the same as follows:

modal + past participle + werden

Examples:

Dem alten Mann *muss geholfen werden*.

*Kann* das Radio nicht *repariert werden*?

Erik *soll* nicht *eingeladen werden*.

Dieser Aufsatz *durfte* nicht *geschrieben werden*.

However, there is one modal that acts quite differently and that is " wollen ".

Er wird *fotografiert werden wollen*.

If we follow the passive modal formula, the above sentence should be like this:

Er *will fotografiert werden*.

Why does wollen become the last element in the sentence but other modals don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a crucial detail. Your passive voice sentence

> Er will fotografiert werden.

indeed exists. The corresponding active voice sentence is

> Er will fotografieren.

---

So what is the following sentence?

> Er wird fotografiert werden wollen.

That's the passive voice sentence of the active voice sentence

> Er wird fotografieren wollen.

That's both Futur I tense rather than Präsens.

Comment: Is the following sentence a double infinitive sentence?                                                             Er wird fotografieren wollen.

Comment: It's a sentence with two infinitives. But such a thing as a "double infinitive sentence" does not exist outside of your learning materials. Because German doesn't care about the number of verbs that you stack. Example: *Du weißt, dass ich heute schwimmen lernen gehen können will.* That's four infinitives. Same building principle. German has a lot of such "half-modals" that take an infinitive as their argument.